# Search autocomplete event handling implementation best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, search, autocomplete

I have a searchbox which listens to keypress and calls the controller action to get results
These results shown for autocomplete as a dropdown. It works functionally.

Currently I have it set on each key press.

The problem is if I type 4/5 characters and debug the app, same line gets executed 4/5 times.

Is there a way to prevent this on the controller (I guess no)?

Is is good to send the request to the server on every character or do it based on time delay such as send the request after every 1 second delay while user keeps typing?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can defined the minimum characters to call the controller method

Answer (score 0):

add this to auto complete so it wait until minimum characters reach

```
minLength: (integer value what you preferred )
```

cheers

Comment: I have set to 2. The problem is when user types multiple characters quickly. Server needs to process just the last one